# can't include modules loaded from lib in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails 5 application (in dev environment) I have some modules to be loaded from the lib folder and included in models. So I set in my *application.rb*

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

the module is something like

**lib/surveyable/surveyable.rb**

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Surveyable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do

    def sjs_elements(&block)
      ....
    end
  end

end
```

which is included in my user model class:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  include Surveyable # <= this doesn't raise any error

  sjs_elements do # <= *** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `sjs_elements' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
     ....
  end

  ....
end
```

I need to manually require it at the beginning of **application.rb** to have it working but this violates rails conventions:

`require_relative '../lib/surveyable/surveyable'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a simple misunderstanding of how rails resolves module names. Adding a directory to the autoload path does not cause rails to look recursively through its subdirectories.

In order for rails to properly load the module it would have to be declared as:

```
# lib/surveyable/surveyable.rb
module Surveyable::Surveyable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

This is because the autoloader deduces the file path based on module nesting.

Or you can move the file to `lib/surveyable.rb`.

But since what you are writing seems to be a model concern I would place it in `app/models/concerns` which is already added to the load path.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused as to why you don't get a name error from `include Surveyable` - but Rail's autoloading is a strange and mysterious beast.

Comment: that was maybe because I had other classes in the same module which were under the correct path like lib/surveyable/sjs_model.rb. thanks a lot